# Why does my LED lamp flash with new driver?

Tags: electrical, led, lamp, electronics

The driver for my LED lamp was broken and I ordered a new one online.
Here you can see the specifications of the old one:
[image]

I tried to match these specifications as good as possible and bought the following new driver:
[image]

After connecting my lamp to the new driver it turns on for a split second and then stays off for 2 more seconds periodically.

Here you can see the specifications of my lamp:
[image]
[image]

Did I buy the correct driver for my lamp? If not, what driver should I use such that my lamp is working without flashing.

I'm happy about any help!!

Comment: What was wrong with the old power supply ("driver")?

Comment: The lamp didnt light up with with the old power supply. So I was suspecting that it was broken. Do you think it could be also a problem related to the LED's? At least the new power supply causes them to flash, which was not the case with the old one.

Comment: The ampere rating do not match.From what I've read LED are sensitive and do NOT limit current by itself...see this question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/14656/what-happens-to-my-led-when-i-supply-too-much-current you find matching led drivers on ali express...

Comment: @Pepe: Did you check the voltage output of the old power supply?

Comment: @Rubus: I didnt take that into account, I actually assumed that 2A would work for my case. I will check if I can get another fitting power supply.

Comment: 2/1.5 = 1.333...maybe ask on electronics.stackexchange if 33% increase is a problem...

Comment: @Rodo: Yes you are right I should really measure if the old power supply is really broken. Will do that asap.

Comment: @Rubus Thats a good Idea thanks! Will do that and hopefully gain more insight.

Comment: From what I was able to find the driver limits the power output, the power supply you purchased does not. Try adding a few ohms resistance in series with the DC to the lamp and see if that stops the blinking. Careful the resistors can get hot. If that works you can get or make a constant current driver that will operate from 12V. Does this have remote control and dimming?

Comment: @Gil No dimming and no remote control, just a foot switch that I currently removed from the circuit. If I can find some suitable resistors to limit the current, I will try it out.

Comment: As @Gil suggests, a resistor of *roughly* 6 ohms, 10 watts, should help, if the issue is excessive current. You could try a 2 ohm fixed resistor in series with a 6 ohm  rheostat to make the repair adjustable. *However*, if each lamp can be shut individually, this might cause problems if they're not *all* lit, because more current would go to the lit lamp than normal.

You might also need a large electrolytic capacitor across the lamps to reduce flicker, perhaps 1,000 microfarads at 35 VDC or more. Note polarity: + of the cap goes to + line.

Comment: This stuff about "too many amps" is plain wrong; the lamp states it draws 1.25A, so by that rationale, the 1.5A adapter that came with it is "too much". You should never run a DC adapter at full capacity anyway, nor rely on a label for a precise indication of output current; actual amps are often less than labeled on cheap ones and more on good ones.

Comment: I suspect the lamp itself is kaput; some of the diodes have failed short, activating the DC supplies short-circuit protection. The new one tries periodically to provide power and quickly shuts off when too much is taken and the output capacitor drains. I'm afraid a new supply won't help, or won't for long. If you can find a dark spot on one of the rings during the brief flash, you should be able to cut off that broken ring and the thing will work like new. Well, 80% like new ;)

Comment: Have you considered contacting the lamp's manufacturer and asking about purchasing an OEM replacement? If _that_ doesn't work, then that wasn't the problem (maybe you can return it). Otherwise, it should be pretty well guaranteed to work.

Comment: Thanks for the update! If you'll spend a moment taking the [tour] you'll see that this is a Question & Answer site, not a general discussion forum. If you'll take your update and make an answer out of it, you can accept it and close this question, since that really is the solution to the problem you'd asked about.

Comment: @FreeMan I have added my answer, I'll accept it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I told my father (it's his LED light) about the flashing of the lamps with the new power supply and he told me that with the old power supply he had the same problem (before he told me it was just broken). Moreover I told him then to check the old power supply together with the electrician in his company and they found out it works fine. So the problem should not be the old power supply. Sorry for the confusion! I will now check if there is a problem with the LED lamps as for example @dandavis suggested in the comments.

Thanks to everyone for the usefull tips :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use some diodes to drop the voltage as well, use something rated at least 3 amps and if it works it could be a permanent fix. Be sure they do not get to hot. If you look at the current curve of a LED the current rises almost exponentially with the voltage once the threshold is reached. A few hundred milivolts the diodes drop will noticeably reduce the current. Your driver puts out 1500 (1.5 Amp) Milliamps until the voltage reaches 12V. At that point it goes from constant current mode to constant voltage mode, which limits the voltage to 12 volts. They make switch mode converters that have the capability of CC/CV. They are not that expensive and would do what you want. They may be sold to charge Lead or Nicad batteries and allow you to adjust both parameters. Ohm's law says you will only get constant current or constant voltage, not both concurrently. You can also get another LED driver unit to replace the one you have.

Comment: I don't think this will help; the lamp wants 12v and the supply provides 12v. If the lamp's innards are all passives like LED strip, it's 3 LEDs in series for ~10v and a resistor dropping the last 2v; a few 100mv won't do much, PWM dimming would be better, and that would be a great lamp btw. If the lamp's innards are actives, like a boosting CC SMPS to drive 8 LEDs in series, it doesn't matter what you feed it in terms of volts, it will take 15W anyway it can; 5v*3a, 10v*1.5a, etc. If there were only LEDs on the other end of the wire, your idea works, but the factory supply wouldn't have.